# Click Animation parent/child

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

I have on `LinearLayout` (I'll call it the parent) with inside an other `LinearLayout` (the child)

When I listen to a click on the child layout, I'd like to make the clickable animation on the parent and not only on the child.

How can I make that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to add a `OnClickListener` to the parent layout and then add the attribute `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to the inner layout. That way, when you press/click on the inner layout, the parent layout will also receive the event and process any animations and if it was being actioned directly.